# Le sens de « en soi(t) » dans, par exemple, « mais en soit je m'en fous »

Tags: sens, expressions, traduction, locutions

(attention : j'ai pour langue maternelle l'anglais, non pas le français. S'il vous plaît pardonnez toute faute que j'ai peut-être faite en écrivant ! )

On peut trouver plusieurs variantes de la partie guillemetée du titre en faisant une recherche sur Google (par exemple, « nan mais en soit/sois je suis d'accord » ), donc je ne vais citer que celle qui m'a incité à faire ce post au départ :

> Oui ça arrive souvent quand je parle à des gens bizarres qu'ils me dislikent. Mais en soit je m'en fous, spirituellement ça me rassure sur le fait que j'ai incontestablement raison. (source : un commentaire sur YouTube ; le contexte exact n'importe pas)

Dans le passage ci-dessus (ainsi que tous les autres qui sont trouvables sur l'Internet comme je l'ai évoqué), c'est le « en soit » qui me rend perplexe. Est-ce une faute de frappe pour « en soi » ? Si c'est le cas, dans quelle acception cette expression est-elle employée là ? Je sais qu'elle se traduit en anglais par « in itself » , mais pourtant, quel que soit le contexte  dans les cas considérés, ni « en soi » ainsi traduit, ni « en soit » autrement traduit semble correct. Est-ce que l'une de ces deux locutions a un usage argotique ou populaire qui m'échappe ? Je n'en ai aucune idée...

Si quelqu'un pouvait m'aider à résoudre ce problème de traduction qui me donne tant de fil à retordre, j'apprécierais vraiment. Merci d'avance !

Comment: On n'a vraiment rien à pardonner parce que l'un des  buts de tous et donc l'un des  vôtres sur ce site est de corriger toute erreur qui a été décelée, de rendre tout aussi lisible que possible. Donc, ne vous faites aucun souci sur ce point.

Comment: Vérifiez dans la correction que vos idées n'ont pas été modifiées et dites si quelque chose ne va pas.

Comment: There is the possibility of a "roll back": https://french.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=rollback

Comment: @LPH Merci, je comprends mieux maintenant comment tout marche ici ^^

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it right and don't forget the "lost in translation" fact sometimes one writes in another language what makes sense in his, since neither French nor English are my primary languages, I had trouble with that.

**En soi**: like you said means intrinsically, in English "in itself".

**En soit**: don't forget that "soit" is the verb *être* (to be) conjugated in *subjonctif*. I give some examples:

« J'ai peur qu'il en soit ainsi » : I'm afraid it's like that.

« Je marche un kilomètre, soit mille mètres » translated to I walk 1 kilometer which is 1000 meters.

So **soit** will take all meaning that verbe (to be) can handle.

Answer (score 1):

« T » dans ce contexte est une erreur : il ne peut pas s'agir du verbe « être » et c'est donc le pronom « soi » qui est utilisé.

En effet, « mais en soi je suis d'accord » n'est pas du français correct.

*Précisions suggérées par un commentaire de [user Reyedy](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43066/le-sens-de-en-soit-dans-par-exemple-mais-en-soit-je-men-fous/43067?noredirect=1#comment87195_43067) :
« En quoi la phrase "Mais en soi, je suis d'accord" est-elle incorrecte ? ».*

« Soi » est un pronom personnel de troisième personne.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soi)) I. − [Employé seul ou renforcé par même] Pronom personnel réfléchi, prédicatif, de troisième personne, sans marque de nombre ou de genre.

On voit dans les exemples ci-dessous que ce qui est représenté est un groupe nominal (pronom), ayant la fonction de sujet ou une autre fonction comme par exemple complément d'objet,  mais que ce groupe n'est pas un pronom à la première personne, et un groupe nominal  est à la troisième personne (caractères gras ajoutés par user LPH)

[réf. 1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=QrkPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA51&dq=%22mais+en+soi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy_rnGuITsAhUnzYUKHQX3BxcQ6AEwJnoECF8QAg#v=onepage&q=%22mais%20en%20soi%22&f=false)
Cette **coutume** prive sa cour d'éclat et de bruit, mais en soi elle a de la grandeur.

[réf. 2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=WneeAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT342&dq=%22mais+en+soi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy_rnGuITsAhUnzYUKHQX3BxcQ6AEwL3oECDkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22mais%20en%20soi%22&f=false) Et nous voilà revenus au **cliché** comme vérité, pas dans l'ostentation, mais en soi.

[réf. 3](https://books.google.fr/books?id=URuiBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT148&dq=%22mais+en+soi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy_rnGuITsAhUnzYUKHQX3BxcQ6AEwA3oECDUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22mais%20en%20soi%22&f=false) Il faut également que l'**instant** considéré non d'une manière relative, mais en soi et dans le sens absolu, soit indivisible, et qu'il demeure indivisible dans un temps quelconque.

[réf; 4](https://books.google.fr/books?id=24a7GIXwn4IC&pg=PA132&dq=%22mais+en+soi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy_rnGuITsAhUnzYUKHQX3BxcQ6AEwBHoECDMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22mais%20en%20soi%22&f=false) […] **il** régénère les êtres par sa chaleur vivifiante , il les éclaire par ses éclatantes illuminations , mais en soi il demeure pur et sans mélange .

[réf. 5](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Nmy6BAAAQBAJ&pg=RA6-PR70&dq=%22mais+en+soi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy_rnGuITsAhUnzYUKHQX3BxcQ6AEwDnoECEYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22mais%20en%20soi%22&f=false) La **pensée**, par conséquent, et la **spéculation** sont en déclin lorsque dépérit quelque autre chose en nous, mais en soi, c'est une réalité qui ne s'affecte pas.

[réf. 6](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Dbcad1Ftts8C&pg=PT54&dq=%22mais+en+soi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy_rnGuITsAhUnzYUKHQX3BxcQ6AEwFnoECFIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22mais%20en%20soi%22&f=false) Ce n'est plus au-dehors de soi que le **poète** va scruter l'étrangeté mais en soi.

Comme on ne suppose pas que « je » serait ici un élément quelconque dans une phrase donnée et qui pourrait ne pas être le représenté, par exemple

«  **Il** n'est pas affecté dans ses réactions, mais en soi, je suis d'accord. »,

il faut évidemment considérer que « soi » est pris comme représentant le sujet « je », et c'est cela qui n'est pas correct. La forme correcte est celle-ci : « en moi-même je suis d'accord ».

Comment: En quoi la phrase "Mais en soi, je suis d'accord" est-elle incorrecte ?

Comment: @Reyedy J'ai apporté une modification à ma réponse de sorte à fournir une explication plus détaillée.

Comment: Je suis désolé mais je ne suis toujours pas d'accord. Je pense que le terme "en soi" est utilisé comme une expression, qui signifie "intrinsèquement" et n'a pas à être conjugué ou accordé avec le sujet. Ex : "je n'aime pas votre façon de présenter les choses, mais en soi je vous rejoins sur le fond". La définition du TLFi précise "sans marque de nombre ni de genre" et je l'interprète donc comme "à ne pas accorder". La phrase "en moi-même je suis d'accord" n'a aucun sens à mes yeux.

Comment: Pour préciser ma vision : dans mon exemple, "en soi" pourrait se remplacer par "sur le sujet en lui-même" -> "Sur le sujet en lui-même, je suis d'accord", ou "à propos de XXX, je suis d'accord". Pour moi, on est dans l'utilisation **2.a)** de la définition du TLFi, à savoir *En soi.Absolument, abstraction faite de toute autre chose.*

Comment: @Reyedy Je n'ai jamais remarqué une telle utilisation de « soi » ; c'est un pronom et donc il faut un représenté ; c'est du nonsense que d'utiliser des pronoms sans qu'il y ait dans la phrase quelque chose qu'ils représentent. Cela dit, je suis assez d'accord, le contexte pour "en moi-même je suis d'accord » n'est pas courant, mais il y en en bien un : « Je ne dis rien, je fais semblant de ne pas comprendre, mais en moi-même, intérieurement, je suis d'accord. ». Pouvez-vous fournir une référence qui montre que ce nouvel usage de « soi » a au moins un certain degré d'acceptation ?

Comment: @Reyedy Je prends l'exemple qui se trouve dans votre référence : « Car rien n'a de sens en soi, mais, de toute chose, le sens véritable est structure (Saint-Exup.,Citad., 1944, p. 660). »; il y a un représenté dans cette phrase ; sans aucun doute c'est « rien », dont la personne est la troisième.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec @Reyedi même si LPH a probablement techniquement raison. "En soi" est communément employé comme une expression voulant dire "intrinsèquement", même quand l'accord avec le sujet n'a pas de sens. Académie Française vs real life.

Answer (score 1):

***En soit*** can't be but a typo here. That's not grammatical.

***En soi*** is possible but probably not of the nicest style.

Alternatives might be:

> *Mais de ça, je m'en fous.*

> *Mais pour ma part, je m'en fous.*

Note also that there is another issue in the excerpt :

> *...des gens bizarres **qu'ils** me dislikent.*

should be:

> *...des gens bizarres **qui** me dislikent.*

---

***En soit*** ne peut pas être autre chose qu'une faute de frappe ici. Ce n'est pas grammatical.

***En soi*** est possible mais pas du style le plus heureux.

D'autres choix peuvent être :

> *Mais de ça, je m'en fous.*

> *Mais pour ma part, je m'en fous.*

On peut aussi noter qu'il y a un autre problème dans cet extrait :

> *...des gens bizarres **qu'ils** me dislikent.*

devrait être :

> *...des gens bizarres **qui** me dislikent.*

Comment: À mon avis c'est plus une faute tout court qu'une faute de frappe. En en parlant autour de moi, je me suis rendu compte que la plupart des gens ne savent pas trop s'il faut mettre un *t* ou non à "*en soi*" :)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat J'utilise *typo* au sens large... https://english.stackexchange.com/a/9482/23719